# Why do I get a protractor script timeout error when trying to click on a button?

Tags: angular, rxjs, protractor

I try to click a button in a protractor test. However, I always get a script timeout error and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The button is inside a material dialog. The dialog is displayed immediately after starting the Angular app. My code looks like this:

```
  it('Dialog 1 check', () => {
    expect(page.getSelect().isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(page.getSaveButton().isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    page.hitSaveButton().then(() => {
     browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(page.getTitelElement())), 1000);
    });
  });
```

```
  getSelect() {
    return element(by.css('select'));
  }

  getTitelElement() {
    return element(by.id('title'));
  }

  getSaveButton() {
    return element(by.id('saveButton'));
  }

  hitSaveButton() {
    return this.getSaveButton().click() as Promise<any>;
  }
```

If I insert `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` at the beginning of the method, I can click the button, but the two expects fail. When adding ignoreSync between the two expects and hitButton, I get a script timeout error too.
Does anyone know a solution for this issue?

Update:
I found a solution: I'm using a rxjs-timer in my app-component to fetch every 60 seconds data from server:

```
    timer(0, 60000).subscribe(() => {
      // data fetch from server
    });
```

When removing this, everything is fine. I checked several variations and the issue is definitely caused by the timmer. Even if I just write a console.log inside the timer, it causes timeout errors. 
Any ideas why rxjs timer destroy protractor tests?

Comment: you overcomplicate code. don't use `.then` syntax, research how to use `async/await`. `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` is no longer supported. Read the docs to see what to use instead. getSaveButton() just returns an element, why not create a variable instead of function. And for `rxjs timer`, it should be another question, you'll have higher chances getting that answered

Comment: By default, protractor waits for all the Angular HTTP and related network functions to complete. If your app keeps polling for data then you will encounter the error. A probable solution is to disable the waitforangular method